# Divs fail to stack and stay together when responsive

Tags: html, responsive-design

I created a simple array using an outer and two inner divs. Each inner div contains and image. All is fine when the site is viewed >800px in width. But <800px, the two inner divs begin to separate vertically. I've tried setting the outer div to relative, and the inner divs to absolute positioning. Nothing seems to affect the separating divs at under about 800px screen size.

This is the site: www.uppervalleynow.com. As you reduce screen with on the "it's happening now..." / "add your event here" the images split vertically on <800px responsive. I have no @media set to 800px.

My goal is to keep the two inner divs aligned (stuck) together at various screen widths.

Thanks!

Comment: This issue seems to be the way the images respond; both containers have images in them.

Comment: Issue resolved: http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/